# Titanium Appcelerator - method needed to replace Ti.UI.currentWindow()

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, commonjs

An inherited project has been implemented using old deprecated methods.

A button loads a new page like so:

**main.js**

```
var thisWindow = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var nav = Titanium.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
    window: thisWindow
});
nav.open();

myButton.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var detailWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor: '#333333',
        exhibitLat: latitude,
        exhibitLon: longitude,
        url: 'mapPage.js'
    });
    thisWindow.nav = nav;
    nav.openWindow(detailWindow, {
            animated: true
        });
};
```

On `mapPage.js` it refers to `Ti.UI.currentWindow()` to use data from `main.js` like so:

**mapPage.js**

```
var window = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var Latitude = window.latitude;
var Longitude = window.longitude;
```

How can I reproduce this method to successfully pass parameters to `mapPage.js` with `require`?

Been scratching my head on this for a while - so some help (with code examples  ) would be most welcome! Thanks

Comment: can you add code where `mapPage.js` is created from `main.js`?

Comment: Just added code snippet above - thanks @Rene

Answer (score 0):

The `url` property is indeed very outdated. Instead you should create the window inside `mapPage` and return that.

mapPage.js:

```
exports.createWindow = function(latitude, longitude){
    var detailWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor: '#333333',
        exhibitLat: latitude,
        exhibitLon: longitude,
        url: 'mapPage.js'
    });
    return detailWindow
}
```

Then your `main.js` will look like this:

```
var nav = Titanium.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
    window: thisWindow
});
nav.open();

myButton.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    thisWindow.nav = nav;
    var detailWindow = require('mapPage').createWindow(latitude, longitude);
    nav.openWindow(detailWindow, {
            animated: true
        });
};
```

I also stripped out the `thisWindow` section. If that gets its "currentWindow" the same way `mapPage.js` got it, you need to replace it with something similar as displayed here.

Comment: How can I use the variables ```exhibitLat``` and ```exhibitLon``` outside of the ```createWindow``` function, whilst still on ```mapPage.js```? ```Ti.API.info('exhibitLon = ' + exhibitLon);``` returns "Can't find variable: exhibitLon". This variable is needed further down on the page....?

Comment: thats javascript scoping, read about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope